was/were + Past Participle and a verb in the -ing form
I am having trouble understanding the grammar structure of the following sentence:

He was done eating.

My problem is trying to explain why the passive form is followed by an ing form.
I do not know the name of this structure. Can anyone explain why?
I'm looking for the grammar rule.

Related and possible duplicate of "I am done" or "I have finished" or "I am finished" or "I finish" and I'm finished vs I finished and Which is correct: “I’m done” or “I have finished”?

Also 1. Is the sentence "We're done" grammatically correct? 2. "I am finished my sandwich" sounds correct but "I am started my sandwich" does not? The last one answers why your sentence is not in the passive voice 3. Why is “I am finished” the Passive Voice?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are various constructions with related meanings.

be done with (someone or something): To be finished with someone or something; to                              cease being involved
or
dealing with someone or something.

I've been working on this essay for hours now, so I'm just going to write the conclusion and be done with it.
That group has been a really negative influence in my life, so I've decided that I'm done with them altogether.
You've hurt me for the last time, Brandon — I'm done with you!

be done: To be finished ... [passive; possibly stative (arguably adjectival) but probably                     transformational]

The roast is still cooking? Sheesh, when is it gonna be done?

be done (+ ing-clause): To be finished or have completed something.

I hope you're done writing that paper because class starts in three minutes.
You're done cleaning your room already?


[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms; amended]
'He was done eating' (an alternative is 'He was finished eating', and another, 'He was through eating' [informal] argues for adjectival use) is of the third type listed. One could argue that this is the be-pluperfect, with 'He was finished eating' = 'He had finished eating'. Compare 'I am come' = 'I have come' (largely poetic nowadays).

Of course, it's an idiom. Things can be so simple.
